# Julia: Is it really possible for rand to throw a zero?

Tags: random, julia

The [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.2-dev/stdlib/Random/#Base.rand) say `rand` draws iid uniformly distributed values in the half-open unit interval [0,1) which includes zero but is rand ever throwing a zero?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible for `rand()` to return zero and `rand()` does not return one.

Software should be designed to work whether or not `iszero(rand())`. And it is 
good practice to provide an appropriate test case. How often does a computer that is continuously generating `rand()` yield zero? Using very rough estimates: about every six weeks.

Sometimes it may be more appropriate to sample from (0.0, 1.0], omitting zero 
while permitting one.  Here is one way to do that.

```
zero_as_one(x::T) where {T<:AbstractFloat} =
    ifelse(iszero(x), one(T), x)

rand1(::Type{T}) where {T<:AbstractFloat} =
    zero_as_one(rand(T))

function rand1(::Type{T}, n::I) where {T<:AbstractFloat, I<:Integer}
    n < 1 && throw(ArgumentError("n must be >= 1"))
    n === one(I) && return rand1(T)
    return map(zero_as_one, rand(T, n))
end
```

Here is a way to sample from (0.0, 1.0), omitting both zero and one.

```
openrand() = openrand(Float64)

openrand(::Type{T}) where {T<:AbstractFloat} =
    let result = rand(T)
        while iszero(result)
            result = openrand(T)
        end
        result
    end

function openrand(::Type{T}, n::I) where {T<:AbstractFloat, I<:Integer}
    n < 1 && throw(ArgumentError("n must be >= 1"))
    n === one(I) && return openrand(T)
    result = Vector{T}(undef, n)
    for i in 1:n
        result[i] = openrand(T)
    end
    return result
end
```

In addition to Julia, C, C++, Fortran, Perl, Python, Ruby, and Spreadsheets
also use the interval [0.0, 1.0) for uniform random sampling. Matlab and R use (0.0, 1.0).  Mathematica uses [0.0, 1.0].

---

[the original thread on discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/is-it-really-possible-for-rand-to-throw-a-zero/28505)